# Is it possible to add new row and save record using lightning data table?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datable

Im trying add new row in lightning data table to create and update records using custom lightning data table. For existing records its updating the values and even dependent picklist showing properly. when i click add row its adding new row but when i click picklist its showing error also its showing all dependent picklist not related to the picklist.

Also, is it possible to add new row and create and update records using custom lightning-datatable? Please refer the below error screenshot and code.

For existing records showing dependent picklist properly and updating the records
[image]

When i click add row its addine new row but when select picklist im getting an error[[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.]
[image]

lWCDatatableWithPicklist.html

```
<div class="slds-var-m-around_small">
        <lightning-button label="New Row" onclick={handleAddRow} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_small">
        <template if:true={data}>
            <c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type
                key-field="Id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onvalueselect={handleSelection}
                draft-values={draftValues}
                oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                onsave={handleSave}
                oncancel={handleCancel}
                hide-checkbox-column>
            </c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type>
        </template>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

lWCDatatableWithPicklist.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire , api } from 'lwc';
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.getCases';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Category_T__c';
import TYPE_DFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Sub_Category_T__c';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

// import {createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', editable: true },
    {
        label: 'Spend_Category_T__c', fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c', fieldName: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistDColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListDOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },

    { label: 'Line Item Description', fieldName: 'Line_Item_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Calculation Description', fieldName: 'Calculation_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'NGO and ILP Discussion', fieldName: 'NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q1', fieldName: 'Q1__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q2', fieldName: 'Q2__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q3', fieldName: 'Q3__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q4', fieldName: 'Q4__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'First Half Budget', fieldName: 'First_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Second Half Budget', fieldName: 'Second_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Total Annual Budget', fieldName: 'Total_Annual_Budget__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },

]

export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    showSpinner = false;
    @track data = [];
    @track accountData;
    @track draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
    @track pickListOptions;
    @track pickListDOptions;


    @api recordId;
    @track records;



        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
    })

    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('Picklist'+data)
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_DFIELD
    })

    wireDPickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('DPicklist',data.values);
            this.pickListDOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListDOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    //here I pass picklist option so that this wire method call after above method
    @wire(fetchAccounts, { pickList: '$pickListOptions',pickDList:'pickListDOptions' })
    accountData(result) {
        this.accountData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));

            this.data.forEach(ele => {
                ele.pickListOptions = this.pickListOptions;
                ele.pickListDOptions=this.pickListDOptions;
            })

            this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        } else if (result.error) {
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    };

    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });

        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }

handleCellChange(event) {
    let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    draftValues.forEach((ele) => {
        this.updateDraftValues(ele);

        const updatedRow = this.data.find((row) => row.Id === ele.Id);

        if (ele.hasOwnProperty('Spend_Category_T__c')) {
            const selectedCategory = ele.Spend_Category_T__c;

            // Filter dependent picklist options based on the selected category
            const filteredDOptions = this.pickListDOptions.filter((option) => {
                // Implement your logic here to filter based on the category
                return option.validFor.includes(this.pickListOptions.findIndex((item) => item.value === selectedCategory));
            });

            // Update only the specific row's dependent picklist options
            updatedRow.pickListDOptions = filteredDOptions;
        }
    });

    // Update only the specific rows that have been modified
    this.data = [...this.data];
}


    handleSave(event) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.saveDraftValues = this.draftValues;
        const recordInputs = this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });

        // Updateing the records using the UiRecordAPi
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Records Updated Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
            this.draftValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occured!!', 'error', 'dismissable');
        }).finally(() => {
            this.draftValues = [];
            this.showSpinner = false;
        });
    }



    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    // This function is used to refresh the table once data updated
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.accountData);
    }

    handleAddRow() {
        // Create a new blank row with default values
        const newRow = {
            Id: '', // Generate a unique identifier if needed
            Name: '',
            Spend_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Spend_Sub_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Line_Item_Description__c: '',
            Calculation_Description__c: '',
            NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c: '',
            Q1__c: '',
            Q2__c: '',
            Q3__c: '',
            Q4__c: '',
            First_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Second_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Total_Annual_Budget__c: '',
            pickListOptions: this.pickListOptions, // Assign picklist options
            pickListDOptions: this.pickListDOptions, // Assign picklist options
        };

        // Add the new row to the data array
        this.data = [...this.data, newRow];

        // Update draft values if needed
        this.draftValues = [...this.draftValues, newRow];
    }
}
```